# Move a file after download to folder in C#

Tags: unity-game-engine

Hi i'm downloading a file in to unity but i need to move the file in to a folder. How can i do this in C#?

[image]

Comment: You mean to set child of object not folder. Window we can see on screenshoot is Hierarchy?

Comment: teapot is only there when you download the file in to the app so it appears at the bottom off the list i need to to go in the "NEWtest" folder

Comment: drag the file using your mouse.

Comment: can do that its a download at runtime

Comment: I don't get why this question is downvoted. Yes, maybe the author should have provided the code snippet where the downloading takes place, so we would have a starting point for C# advice. But still, this is a valid question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you mean how to put the game object as a child of another? (That's what it looks like from your screenshot)

If so, you can accomplish that by setting your game-object's transform's parent to the transform of the "folder" you want to put it into.

Something like:
teapot.transform.SetParent(NEWTest.transform);

http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.SetParent.html has more information.

Comment: `targetObject.transform.SetParent(NEWTest);` but getting this error: The name `NEWTest' does not exist in the current context

Comment: Alternatively, you could do `GameObject.Find("Name of the object")`

Comment: public GameObject NewParant;  
targetObject.transform.SetParent(NewParant.transform);